# Error while starting synchronize

Tags: sql-server-2008, merge-replication

I'm using merge replication for database synchronization. I'm getting the folllowing error when launching the replication monitor.I can able to access both sides. Stil having the problem.

> Error messages: The process could not
>   connect to Subscriber 'DTECH\SQL2008'.
>   (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number:
>   MSSQL_REPL20084) 
>   Network Interfaces: The system
>   detected a possible attempt to
>   compromise security. Please ensure
>   that you can contact the server that
>   authenticated you. (Source:
>   MSSQLServer, Error number:
>   -2146892976) Cannot generate SSPI context (Source: MSSQLServer, Error
>   number: -2146892976) The subscription
>   to publication 'Pub_Smster' could not
>   be verified. Ensure that all Merge
>   Agent command line parameters are
>   specified correctly and that the
>   subscription is correctly configured.
>   If the Publisher no longer has
>   information about this subscription,
>   drop and recreate the subscription. 
>   (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number:
>   MSSQL_REPL-2147201019)

Anyone know abt this error? Whr I'm missing?